# join two tables by three columns including the id's

Tags: sql, join

I have the following tables:

table1

```
+----------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------+---------+
| dlr_code | dlr_yrmon | country | num_repair | num_vehicle |  cost   |
+----------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------+---------+
| J5631    |    201006 | USA     |         10 |          10 | 1300.52 |
| 01031    |    201312 | KEN     |          1 |           1 | 110.73  |
```

and

table 2

```
+-------------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| repair_date |  country_repaired   |              repair_dealer              |
+-------------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| 30/06/2010  | UNITED STATES(USA)  | PREIGE DUDIN(J5631)                     |
| 28/05/2010  | UNITED KINGDOM(GBR) | BROTRS , LILN(11126)                    |
```

The idea is to merge/join table 1 into table 2 tables by year, month, country and dealer code, so the following columns will be in table 2: num_repair, num_vehicle, cost are added in table 2.

Please, let me know if you need more information. Any help will be really appreciate it.

Thanks, mils

Comment: Providing some sample output might make this a lot clearer.

Comment: So the issue is that the country and dlr code are in between the `()` in table 2?

Comment: You need to tell us which SQL platform you are using since it changes significantly -- eg MS SQL, Oracle, DB2, MySql etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
from table1 t1 inner join
table2 t2
on t2.repair_dealer like concat('%',t1.dlr_code,'%')
and t1.dlr_yrmon = concat(DATEPART(yyyy,t2.repair_date), DATEPART(mm,t2.repair_date))
and t2.country_repaired like concat('%',t1.country,'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the platform I can only give you how to join on year an month:

```
SELECT t2.*, num_vehicle, num_repair
FROM table_2 t2
LEFT JOIN table_1 t1 on  
       year(t2.repair_date) = substring(t1.dlr_yrmon,1,4) 
  AND  month(t2.repair_date) = substring(t1.dlr_yrmon,5,2)
```

This technique can be extended to other columns in your data but I need to know the platform so I know the best way to find `(` and `)` in your strings.